# XSS injection and innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xss, innerhtml

I am trying to learn about XSS vulnerabilities and am having some issue grasping the concept.  I have a test site http://mytestpage/index.html and am trying to launch an alert box via xss from a secondary page http://xsstest.html.  I can not seem to get the alert to occur.  I think my issue is that the code from my xsstest page is not injecting into my mytestpage/index.html page.  I am trying to use innerhtml as the posts I read seemed to leverage this in XSS testing.  I am fairly certain that I am not using the innerhtml correctly or pehaps it is not the right "tool for the job" and i am running down the wrong path.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

My code for the XSS test is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
     <title>XSS TEST PAGE</title>
   </head>
<body>

   <body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">

      <form method="POST" id="test" onsubmit="test()" action="http://mytestpage/index.html" >

      </form> 

   </body>


    <script>
        function test(){
            alert("Hiya buddy!");
        }

        document.getElementById().innerHTML = test();
    </script>

</html>
```

The test homepage code is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
     <title>My Test Home Page</title>
   </head>

    <body>

        <form method="post">
            <label>Enter Your Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="myname">
            <button class="btn" type="submit" name="action" value="submit">Submit</button>
        </form> 

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Forget about the secondary page; start by typing a value in manually in the “Enter Your Name” box and submitting it. Look at the source of the result. Repeat to create the HTML you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This right here is no bueno:

```
    <script>
        function test( ){
            alert("Hiya buddy!");
        }

        document.getElementById().innerHTML = test();
    </script>
```

`document.getElementById()` requires you pass it the ID of an element. So, for example, if there's a `div` on the page with the ID of `#alert`, you'd do `document.getElementById('alert')`.

You also can't assign a function to the inner HTML of an element. You need to create a `script` element and then append it to the document or another element. Instead, try:

```
<script>
  let myTest = document.createElement('script')
  myTest.text = `
    function test() {
      alert('Hiya buddy!')
    };

    test();
  `
  const body = document.querySelector('body')
  body.appendChild(myTest)
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, rookie mistakes on my part.  I apperciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing XSS. You are simply displaying alert upon form submission. That too has error that document.getElementById() requires a id to select the element.

XSS is done where you have some input to enter. SO you cannot do XSS in XSStest page but you can do it from test home page code by changing it as

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <title>My Test Home Page</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form method="post" action="some page url">
        <label>Enter Your Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="myname">
        <button class="btn" type="submit" name="action" value="submit">Submit</button>
    </form> 

</body>
```

And Suppose the page whose url you have given in action attribute is like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
 <body>
  Name is: <%=request.getParameter("myname")%>
 </body> 
</HTML>
```

I have assumed you are using jsp here.

Now when you enter XSS payload in inputbox in this page and submit it the page whose url you have given will open up and display the alert as you have not sanitized the input value before using it in      second page.